# connect to ipsec vpn on sonicwall device from a powershell script: Guidance?

Tags: windows, vpn, powershell

Win2012-R2

We have a vpn network device that can surface ipsec and pptp vpn endpoints.

I can see docs for various vpn commands in powershell, e.g.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554820.aspx

But it takes more than a single command, I believe, to bring up a connection and route traffic over it.

Is there some documentation or outline of at least the steps needed to bring up such a connection from powershell? (And ideally, to monitor that connection and rekick it if it goes down for some reason.)

Note: This is for "peer to peer" operation. There is no domain or active directory present, on either side of the connection.

We do not want to install any vpn client apps. The need is to spin up clean instance, and run scripts on it to connect up the vpn back to hq.

(I know with cygwin and ssh this is easy, but strongly prefer to do this with native Windows tools)

Comment: Dont wanna use the GVC client ? You can push login script and such from the client

Comment: @yagmoth555 No, do not want to install or use anything. We need to drive it all from script. Updating OP...

Answer (score 1):

This should provide some guidance on how to put those PowerShell cmdlets together: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj613766.aspx.